# Formula for total differential with respect to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $(x,y)$ denote Cartesian coordinates and $(r,\theta)$ the polar coordinates.

That is, $x=r\cos\theta,~~y=r\sin\theta$ and then it is said that for the total derivatives, we have
$$
dr = \frac{x}{r}dx+\frac{y}{r}dy
$$
$$
d\theta=\frac{-y}{r^2}dx+\frac{x}{r^2}dy.
$$

I do understand the formula for $dr$, because 
$$
r=r(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
and hence 
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=2x\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{x}{r},
$$
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{r}.
$$

But I do not see how to get the formula for $d\theta$. How to get the formula?

The only thing I can see is that, for example,
$$
\theta=\arccos(x/r).
$$

Comment: What's the difficulty in applying the chain rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stuck at finding the derivative of $x\mapsto\arccos(x)$, take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_trigonometric_functions

Here is an alternative way.

Note that
$$
dx=\cos\theta\, dr+r(-\sin\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{x}{r}dr-yd\theta\\
dy=\sin\theta\, dr+r\cos\theta\, d\theta=\frac{y}{r}dr+xd\theta
$$
You can guess what's the next step: write $d\theta, dr$ in terms of $dx,dy$.

Comment: Your alternative way worked. Just for interest: If I stick to my original way and I use that $\theta=\arccos(x/r)$, I get that $d\theta=-\frac{1}{y}dx$. How could this yield the desired result?

Comment: Your calculation is incorrect: $d\theta=\theta_xdx+\theta_ydy$. The part $\theta_ydy$ is missing; also, $\theta_x$ should be $\frac{-y}{r^2}$. Apply the chain rule carefully and note that $r$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3):

The [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the transformation  polar coordinates versus cartesian coordinates is 
$$
\pmatrix{dx\\dy}=
\pmatrix{\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}& \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\\\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}& \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}}\pmatrix{dr\\ d\theta}=
\pmatrix{\cos\theta& -r\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&r\cos\theta}\pmatrix{dr\\ d\theta}.
$$
Hence, by inverting the matrix, we get
$$
\pmatrix{dr\\ d\theta}=
\pmatrix{\cos\theta& -r\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&r\cos\theta}^{-1}\pmatrix{dx\\dy}=\frac{1}{r}
\pmatrix{r\cos\theta& r\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta}\pmatrix{dx\\dy}\\
=\frac{1}{r}
\pmatrix{x& y\\-y/r&x/r}\pmatrix{dx\\dy}=\pmatrix{\dfrac{x}{r}dx+\dfrac{y}{r}dy\\\dfrac{-y}{r^2}dx+\dfrac{x}{r^2}dy}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

When $x>0$ you have $\theta=\arctan{y\over x}$, hence
$${\partial\theta\over\partial x}={-y\over x^2+y^2},\qquad{\partial\theta\over\partial y}={x\over x^2+y^2}\ .$$
In reality these formulas hold in the full punctured plane.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$ \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}z} \tan^{-1}(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$$

in

$${\rm d}\theta = \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)\right) {\rm d x} + \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial y} \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)\right) {\rm d y}$$

to get

$$ {\rm \theta} = \frac{x {\rm d y}-y {\rm d}x}{x^2+y^2} $$